# Preposition confusion problem

Tags: prepositions

I am just a bit confused about prepositions and where is the best situation to use them like a pro.
For example, I need to say

> "We have a few authors who are popular ___ philosophy".

or another one:

> The most popular authors ___ philosophy.

Well, what should I do? in, for, of?
If there is any logical principle I will be happy to learn it I just do not like this confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps someone else can provide a more general and logical approach to prepositions, but I'll give you my take on the sentences you provided:

> We have a few authors who are popular **in** philosophy

Notice that in this, "popular" is an adjective and "philosophy" is a noun.

- "We have a few authors who are popular **in** philosophy." This is correct. This describes the *context* of the authors' popularity.
- "For" in this context would be used to describe *purpose*. Philosophy
  does not utilize popularity, so "for" makes no sense here.
- "Of" would also not be used here. Using "of" in this example would
  imply that the authors' popularity *consists of philosophy*, which does
  not make sense. You can modify some adjectives with "of," but this doesn't work with
  "popular." For example, you could say "The glass is full," but if you
  wish to say that water fills the glass, you would say, "The glass is
  full **of** water."

Your second example is a little more ambiguous because it is not a complete sentence. But notice that the words surrounding the blank space, "authors" and "philosophy," are both nouns. There are a couple options here:

- "The most popular authors **of** philosophy" means that the *popular authors' works are philosophical.* In this case, "of" describes what kind of authors they are.
- "The most popular authors **in** philosophy" means that the authors are popular *within the subject of philosophy.* The use of "in" does not necessarily describe what kind of authors they are, but it is strongly implied from the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem somehow.